# Consuming web services from Windows Embedded Compact 7 (windows CE 7)

Tags: windows-ce

What are the options for consuming web services (hosted for example in Windows Azure) from Windows Embedded Compact 7? 
WCF from Compact Framework 3.5 is one possibility, I guess. Are there any others?
Can I access web services directly from my Silverlight (C++) application?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this myself, but you could try using [SPROXY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ztta389h%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) tool shipped with visual studio.

From MSDN: SPROXY.EXE is a command line tool that generates native C++ client code for accessing an XML Web service based on a WSDL description.

Comment: Thanks for your answer regarding SPROXY. Digged a bit more and found a complete guidance here: http://wcfguidanceformobile.codeplex.com/

Comment: @user566671 I think that document will guide you through WCF with .net compact framework or managed silverlight, but I was not able to find any reference to native Silverlight there. However I did find a video post on how to communicate native Silverlight with .netcf, you may find it useful: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikehall/archive/2010/06/23/combining-net-compact-framework-and-silverlight-for-windows-embedded.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the video. The idea is very ingenious indeed. Quite complicated, but ingenious and perhaps very useful for some scenarios :).